# Will minify work with symbolic links

Tags: php, linux, git, minify, symlink

Using https://code.google.com/p/minify/ for the first time.  I would like to include all associated files in a directory outside of the root, and put a symlink in my root public directory to point to the appreciate directory in minify (i.e. `min`).  The reasons for wanting to do so is that I wish to clone the repository as a git module.  My initial attempts to do so result in a 400 error.  Is doing so possible?

Comment: I think you will need an extra step to `follow symlinks` somehow.. Will need to do a POC to prove also related: http://code.google.com/p/minify/issues/detail?id=199

Comment: @Pogrindis Pls, could you elaborate?...